# Link Navigation View Controller cell to a Web View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a navigation controller with multiple cells. I want to link each of the cells to a webpage in a web view. However, I don't want to create another view controller for each cell. Is it possible to create 1 view controller and link all cells to the same view controller but make a different webpage show up in the web view for each cell? For example, there is cell 1 and cell 2. They both link to one view controller with a web view in the view controller. When you click cell 1, it brings you to the view controller and in the web view it brings you to http://example.com. When you click cell 2, it brings you to the same view controller as cell 1 but in the web view, it brings you to http://example.com/1. How can I do that?

Comment: UINavigationController doesn't have 'cells'. Did you mean UITableViewController, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a property in your `viewcontroller` which holds the URL you want to request.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *url;
```

When you click on a cell assign the URL of the cell accordingly to the property of your `viewcontroller`

Your viewcontroller should look something like this.

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RSViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *url;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "RSViewController.h"

@interface RSViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end

@implementation RSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webview.delegate = self;

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
    [self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Did start loading");
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Did finish loading");
}

@end
```

Now you just need a reference to your `viewcontroller` in your `tableviewcontroller`and set the `url`property on cell click.

Comment: What view controller do you mean? I have one Table View Controller where the cells are and another view controller where the web view is.

Comment: the viewcontroller where your webview is